# Problem with differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose that $f$ is a differentiable function of a single variable and 
$F(x,y)$ is defined by $F(x,y) = f(x^2 − y)$.

a) Show that $F$ satisfies the partial differential equation $\frac{∂F}{￼￼∂x} +2x\frac{∂F}{∂y} =0$.

b) Given that $F(0,y) = \sin y$ for all $y$, find a formula for $F(x,y)$.

Don't know how to do b). Can someone help me?

Comment: There's something wrong with the formatting.  Is it supposed to just say $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}$ for the first term?

Answer (score 1):

You know that $$F(x,y) = f(x^2-y)$$
ie $$F(0,y) = f(-y) = \sin y \Longrightarrow f(y) = \sin-y = -\sin y$$
$$\text{if } f(y) = -\sin y \Longrightarrow f(x^2-y) = -\sin (x^2-y)$$

Therefore your solution is $F(x,y) = -\sin (x^2 - y)$
or $$F(x,y) = \sin(y-x^2)$$

Answer (score 0):

You have
$$
F(0,y) = f(0^2 - y) = f(-y) = \sin(y)
$$
that is
$$
f(z) = \sin(-z) = -\sin(z).
$$
And so
$$
F(x,y) = f(x^2 - y) = -\sin(x^2 - y).
$$

Comment: @Raymondwu: Glad to help.